How can you calculate the distance between in a spreadsheet?
I want to calculate the distance between an address and multiple addresses in a list.
I want to use this calculation to quickly determine which addresses fall within
a delivery radius.
The addresses are coming from a farm delivery-type map.
It would be an added benefit to be able to add fixed distance circles to the map.

If want a solution targeted at your specific data, [edit] your question to include sample data as well as an example of your  expected/desired results (both in markdown text).

Please [edit] your question to focus on one of the two questions.  One is about Sheets (calculations) and the other is about Maps (circles). Include a link to a sample of the farm map that you reference so we better understand what you mean.

You only need high-school math to calculate the Euclidean distance between two points with the Pythagorean theorem.
To get a real-world driving distance, use an online map service. See my GoogleMapsDistance custom function for sample code.

Google Sheets doesn't provide this functionality natively.
You can however add a script to your spreadsheet that will add map-related functionality.
@doubleunary's script GoogleMapsDistance is an example of how this can be accomplished.
Take a look at it and others you can find by searching to decide what works best for your needs and comfort level.
For example, Google Maps Formulas for Google Sheets has a spreadsheet ready to go that you can copy to your drive with various custom Sheets/Maps functions.
